# Should the Stack Overflow blog and Meta Stack Overflow be connected in some way?

Tags: discussion, meta, blog

Whenever I'm looking for something on the workings and rules of Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow that I know I read somewhere, the first thing I do is go to my favourites here on Meta Stack Overflow. *Not there.* Hmmm ... let's search Meta Stack Overflow, maybe I didn't put it in my favourite list. *Still, not quite.* Maybe it was on the blog somewhere? *Yes!*

I think the blog has a great deal of information that could have been posted on Meta Stack Overflow, because it contains lots of stuff on how the site works and why.

I also came across several questions I'd also have asked (if someone else hadn't done it for me already), and often the answer said "that's over on the blog".

I think it'd be a good idea if certain blog posts could be marked in some way, so that they would automatically appear here on Meta Stack Overflow. That probably would reduce the amount of questions for stuff that's answered "over on the blog". The only issue is, since the blog is read-only, the meta-post corresponding to it would have to be protected from editing in some way I guess.

Comment: Hmm. What specifically are you missing on meta that isn't covered in the [huge Community FAQ list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)? If there's something, it might be worth adding an adapted version of a blog entry to this FAQ.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask a question about the feature, and have someone provide an answer containing a link to the blog? That solves the problem of having "special" read-only Meta posts, and it also quite nicely follows the Q&A format that we hold sacred here.

Comment: @slhck As an example, the "when will my site graduate" series of blog posts has some information about beta sites that isn't easily discoverable on Meta (or may not actually be on meta).  Actually, I don't see any Area 51 questions in the FAQ, though they seem to be asked a lot.

Comment: @slhck That's not a bad idea. One of the questions that made me post this was one asking for the meaning of "%" on CW posts. One of the answers said "Jeff describes it on the blog". If stuff that people ask is answered on the FAQ you linked to (which I had never seen before BTW, favourited now), that should be the first thing they get pointed to. If there's questions that are purely answered within the blog, maybe it'd be worth it adding that to the FAQ.

Comment: @Cody I think if stuff is answered within the FAQ as well as the blog, an answer should point to the FAQ. The FAQ could then contain a basic answer as well as a link to the (probably a lot more detailed) blog post that explains the feature. If stuff that people ask questions about is answered exclusively on the blog, I think it should be added to the FAQ if it's something that gets asked frequently.

Comment: What FAQ are you talking about? There's no limit on the amount of information that can be in an answer on Meta, though. That's the whole point. You can link to both.

Comment: @Cody I meant the one that slhck linked to. There's lots of stuff answered in that one, but not everyone finds that post easily when looking for an answer to a specific question, because it doesn't match their search patterns to a huge extent.